# C# Facebook SDK - How to use web forms to server side authorize canvas application

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, authorization, token

There are lots of sample applications in MVC but the current project I'm working on requires that I use web forms.

I can authorize the application using the javascript method but I want to use server side.   Below is what I started with on the page.load

```
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.client_id = AppId;
parameters.client_secret = appSecret;
parameters.response_type = "code";
//parameters.state = state;
parameters.redirect_uri = "http://fb.local/page.aspx";

// The requested response: an access token (token), an authorization code (code), or both (code token).
parameters.response_type = "token";

// list of additional display modes can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display
//parameters.display = "popup";

// add the 'scope' parameter only if we have extendedPermissions.
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ExtendedPermissions))
parameters.scope = ExtendedPermissions;

// generate the login url
var fb = new FacebookClient();
var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);

Response.Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri, true);
```

I can authorize but I'm  not able to get the access token from the URL.

On the next page I can view source and see the access token in the url bar but I'm not sure how to go about getting it into the code.  once I have the token, I'm all set.

```
page.aspx#access_token=AAACrxQhmdpY
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to this code on my page load and works, its not a very clean code, but you may figure out how to change it for your best use. so the algorithm is that when the page loads you redirect the user to Facebook authentication page using response.redirect to a string that contains three parameters:your app ID(appid), what permissions you are asking your user(scope), where you want Facebook to redirect the user after authorization, and a parameter as state which i guess it should be a random number. so after the user authorized your application he/she will be redirected to your page, with a request URL that contains the same state you prepared Facebook with(and you can use to identify who which request was which if there are many requests i guess) and also a new "code" parameter which you pass on to Facebook to obtain access token, you can use Facebook c# sdk to obtain the access token.in my code there is a line that says "if code is not null, go to alireza" and alireza is a line tag after the response.redirect code, this is because you dont want the process to be repeated all over and over (and of course probably the browser show an error).

```
        int intstate;
        string strstate;
        string redirecturltofb;
        string scope;
        string appid;
        code = Request.QueryString["code"];

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
        {
            goto alireza; 
        }

        appid = "424047057656831";
        scope = "user_about_me,user_activities,user_groups,email,publish_stream,user_birthday";
        intstate = 45; 
        strstate = Convert.ToString(intstate);
        redirecturltofb = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + appid + "&redirect_uri=http://test5-2.apphb.com/&scope=" + scope + "&state=" + strstate;
        Response.Redirect(redirecturltofb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Javascript SDK to get access token back to code behind.

Use **FB.Init** as in http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started

and do post back on certain conditions to get the access token.

Thank you,

Dharmendra